# WSGI cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-wsgi

I'm getting this error

> 'path-to/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

I've never had it before having loaded many Python / Django projects by

```
mkdir directory
cd directory
virtualenv env 
env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then FTP in the files and then

```
env/bin/python manage.py migrate
env/bin/python manage.py collectstatic
env/bin/python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Today it isn't working.  I've read a number of posts with similar issues but they seem to be due to different versions of python.  Mine aren't.  Any ideas.

**EDIT Traceback added**

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=8982): Target WSGI script '/var/www/mattscott/mainapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=8982): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/mattscott/mainapp/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/www/mattscott/mainapp/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
     application = get_wsgi_application()
   File "/var/www/mattscott/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
   File "/var/www/mattscott/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
   File "/var/www/mattscott/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
     self._setup(name)
   File "/var/www/mattscott/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
   File "/var/www/mattscott/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
     __import__(name)
   ImportError: No module named mainapp.settings
```

Comment: Please show the exact command you were running when you got that error, the *full* traceback, and the code of the wsgi file itself.

Comment: As you appear you may be using mod_wsgi based on the little of the error message you get, supply the full error and any traceback from the Apache error log. Also try temporarily enabling ``DEBUG`` in the Django settings file to see if that works.

Comment: `DEBUG = True` is set and I'm getting a 500 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution but I expect it is the symptom of something else wrong (I'm hoping Graham will explain).

I've added:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

to `wsgi.py`